# Render to texture attached to Frame Buffer Object (texture appears black)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I have generated a frame buffer object(FBO), bind it, attached a texture to its `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. Then ensure that I get its status as `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`. I have another texture(which is displaying on display), let's call it `workingTexture`. Now I want to render this `workingTexture` onto FBO, so I bind this FBO and then render `workingTexture`.
Then I bind default frame buffer(reserved for display) and try to render the texture attached to FBO, thinking that I will get my texture onto display, but I get black texture.

Relevant code

code to generate workingTexture...

```
int[] workingTexture = new int[1];

glGenTextures(1, workingTexture, 0); // generate workingTexture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);  // attach it to TEXTURE_UNIT0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, workingTexture[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
```

code to generate fbo

```
int[] fboName = new int[1];
int[] fboTextureName = new int[1];
final int fboTextureUnit = 1;  // attach this texture to texture unit GL_TEXTURE1
glGenFramebuffers(1, fboName, 0);

int generatedTextureNameForFBO =
                generateTextureForFBO(fboTextureUnit,
                        width, height);
fboTextureName[0] = generatedTextureNameForFBO;

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboName[0]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                GL_TEXTURE_2D, generatedTextureNameForFBO, 0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            // created FBO is not complete
            throw new RuntimeException("FBO status INCOMPLETE ");

        }
```

method used to generate texture attached to fbo

```
 private int generateTextureForFBO(@IntRange(from = 0) final int textureUnit,
                                  @IntRange(from = 1) final int width,
                                  @IntRange(from = 1) final int height) {
    int[] textureName = new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1, textureName, 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + textureUnit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  //        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  //        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  //        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  //        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
  //        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
  //        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return textureName[0];
}
```

Now coming to drawing part...

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //renderTex(mViewMatrix, 0, texProgram);  // this texture is drawing on screen

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboName[0]);
    renderTex(mViewMatrix, 0, texProgram);   // rendering workingTexture onto FBO

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    renderTex(mViewMatrix, fboTextureUnit[0], texProgram);  // texture appears black

}
```

renderTex is a simple method to render texture. It is working fine.

Also I have checked for `GL_ERROR` but there is no error.

My understanding of application created FBO is that every read and write `glCall` will happen on currently bound FBO, so is my understanding of FBO incorrect, or is there some error in my code.

Platform OpenGL|es 20 on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture which is generated in `generateTextureForFBO` is mipmap incomplete.

If you do not generate [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (by [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)), then setting the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is important. Since the default filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` the texture would be mipmap incomplete, if you don not change the minifying function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

Set the texture minifying function (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`) by [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexParameter.xhtml):

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```